# "Failed to end tracking the pointer, because it is not being tracked" exception in PointerPressed

Tags: xaml, mfc, winrt-xaml, c++-winrt, pointer-events

I am getting the above mentioned exception in PointerPressed that too only in the case of MFC application hosted using XAML Islands. In normal UWP application it is working fine. Essentially no other Pointer events are fired in this scenario (Released, Canceled, CaptureLost,Exited etc) but we need to handle some UI changes in PointerReleased.

Kindly suggest any workarounds for the same.